# How to Test Performance of Titanium app

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

many devloper are now developing the iphone app ..in titanium platform . how to check the performance of the app and how to find the memory leaks and other constraits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can Check the performance and Memory leaks of titanium app . using simple steps

We our app get built.go to built folder and side that you will find the iphone inside you can see xcode project... Open that in Xcode Now you can test the app

please go through the docs given below :

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Managing+Memory+and+Finding+Leaks